# Is it safe to interleave manual realWorld# state passing with an arbitrary Monad

Tags: arrays, haskell, vector, primitive, massiv

Consider this function that generates a list for an arbitrary `Monad`:

```
generateListM :: Monad m => Int -> (Int -> m a) -> m [a]
generateListM sz f = go 0
  where go i | i < sz = do x <- f i
                           xs <- go (i + 1)
                           return (x:xs)
             | otherwise = pure []
```

Implementation maybe isn't perfect, but it is presented here solely for demonstration of the desired effect, which is pretty straightforward. For example if a monad is a list well get list of lists:

```
λ> generateListM 3 (\i -> [0 :: Int64 .. fromIntegral i])
[[0,0,0],[0,0,1],[0,0,2],[0,1,0],[0,1,1],[0,1,2]]
```

What I'd like to do is to achieve the same affect, but for `ByteArray` instead of a List. As it turns out, this is much trickier than I thought when I first stumbled upon this problem. The end goal is to use that generator to implement `mapM` in [massiv](https://github.com/lehins/massiv/issues/24), but that is besides the point.

The approach that requires the least effort is to use a function `generateM` from [vector](https://www.stackage.org/haddock/lts-12.22/vector-0.12.0.2/Data-Vector-Primitive.html#v:generateM) package while doing a bit of manual conversion. But as it turns out there is a way to achieve at least a factor of x2 performance gain with this neat little trick of handling the state token manually and interleaving it with the monad:

```
{-# LANGUAGE MagicHash           #-}
{-# LANGUAGE ScopedTypeVariables #-}
{-# LANGUAGE UnboxedTuples       #-}
import           Data.Primitive.ByteArray
import           Data.Primitive.Types
import qualified Data.Vector.Primitive    as VP
import           GHC.Int
import           GHC.Magic
import           GHC.Prim

-- | Can't `return` unlifted types, so we need a wrapper for the state and MutableByteArray
data MutableByteArrayState s = MutableByteArrayState !(State# s) !(MutableByteArray# s)

generatePrimM :: forall m a . (Prim a, Monad m) => Int -> (Int -> m a) -> m (VP.Vector a)
generatePrimM (I# sz#) f =
  runRW# $ \s0# -> do
    let go i# = do
          case i# <# sz# of
            0# ->
              case newByteArray# (sz# *# sizeOf# (undefined :: a)) (noDuplicate# s0#) of
                (# s1#, mba# #) -> return (MutableByteArrayState s1# mba#)
            _ -> do
              res <- f (I# i#)
              MutableByteArrayState si# mba# <- go (i# +# 1#)
              return (MutableByteArrayState (writeByteArray# mba# i# res si#) mba#)
    MutableByteArrayState s# mba# <- go 0#
    case unsafeFreezeByteArray# mba# s# of
      (# _, ba# #) -> return (VP.Vector 0 (I# sz#) (ByteArray ba#))
```

We can use it in the same fashion as before, except now we'll get a primitive `Vector`, which is backed by `ByteArray`, which is what I really need:

```
λ> generatePrimM 3 (\i -> [0 :: Int64 .. fromIntegral i])
[[0,0,0],[0,0,1],[0,0,2],[0,1,0],[0,1,1],[0,1,2]]
```

This seems to work great, performs well for ghc version 8.0 and 8.2, except that there is a regression in 8.4 and 8.6, but that issue is orthogonal.

Finally I get to the actual question. Is this approach really safe? Is there some edge case that I am not aware of that could bite me later? Any other suggestions or opinions are welcome as well with regard to the above function.

PS. `m` doesn't have to be restricted to a `Monad`, an `Applicative` would work just fine, but the example is a bit clearer when it is presented with `do` syntax.

Comment: Maybe I am not completely understanding your goals, but have you considered using, say, `ST s` or any other `PrimMonad`? I would attempt to achieve the same performance through known-safe methods before resorting to low-level primitives.

Comment: @chi That's a good question. It's not totally obvious, but it is impossible to use either `PrimMonad` or `ST` in order to achieve the desired function.

Comment: @chi, I stand corrected, `primitive` does indeed has a function I was looking for. :) See my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**TLDR;** From what I gathered so far, it does seem to be a safe way to generate a primitive `Vector` in a way I originally proposed. Moreover, the use of `noDuplicate#` is not really necessary, since all of the operations are idempotent and order of operations will not have an affect on the resulted array(s).

*Disclosure*: It's been over a year since I first thought about that problem. It was only last month that I tried to get back to it. Reason why I am saying this is because checking out [primitive](https://www.stackage.org/package/primitive) package now I noticed a new module `Data.Primitive.PrimArray` to me. As @chi mentioned in the comments, there isn't really a need to drop down to the low-level primitives in order to get a solution, since it might already exist. Which contains exactly the function [generatePrimArrayA](https://www.stackage.org/haddock/lts-13.4/primitive-0.6.4.0/Data-Primitive-PrimArray.html#v:generatePrimArrayA), which was exactly what I was looking for (a bit simplified copy of the source code):

```
newtype STA a = STA {_runSTA :: forall s. MutableByteArray# s -> ST s (PrimArray a)}

runSTA :: forall a. Prim a => Int -> STA a -> PrimArray a
runSTA !sz =
  \(STA m) -> runST $ newPrimArray sz >>= \(ar :: MutablePrimArray s a) -> m (unMutablePrimArray ar)

generatePrimArrayA :: (Applicative f, Prim a) => Int -> (Int -> f a) -> f (PrimArray a)
generatePrimArrayA len f =
  let go !i
        | i == len = pure $ STA $ \mary -> unsafeFreezePrimArray (MutablePrimArray mary)
        | otherwise =
          liftA2
            (\b (STA m) -> STA $ \mary -> writePrimArray (MutablePrimArray mary) i b >> m mary)
            (f i)
            (go (i + 1))
   in runSTA len <$> go 0
```

Just as a fun exercise if we go through the basic simplification with usual reduction rules we get a very similar thing to what I had in the first place:

```
generatePrimArrayA :: forall f a. (Applicative f, Prim a) => Int -> (Int -> f a) -> f (PrimArray a)
generatePrimArrayA !(I# n#) f =
  let go i# = case i# <# n# of
                0# -> pure $ \mary s# ->
                        case unsafeFreezeByteArray# mary s# of
                          (# s'#, arr'# #) -> (# s'#, PrimArray arr'# #)
                _ -> liftA2
                     (\b m ->
                        \mary s ->
                          case writeByteArray# mary i# b s of
                            s'# -> m mary s'#)
                     (f (I# i#))
                     (go (i# +# 1#))
   in (\m -> runRW# $ \s0# ->
                case newByteArray# (n# *# sizeOf# (undefined :: a)) s0# of
                  (# s'#, arr# #) -> case m arr# s'# of
                                       (# _, a #) -> a)
      <$> go 0#
```

Here is my version adjusted for an `Applicative` instead of a `Monad`:

```
generatePrimM :: forall m a . (Prim a, Applicative m) => Int -> (Int -> m a) -> m (PrimArray a)
generatePrimM (I# sz#) f =
  let go i# = case i# <# sz# of
                0# -> runRW# $ \s0# ->
                      case newByteArray# (sz# *# sizeOf# (undefined :: a)) s0# of
                        (# s1#, mba# #) -> pure (MutableByteArrayState s1# mba#)
                _  -> liftA2
                      (\b (MutableByteArrayState si# mba#) ->
                         MutableByteArrayState (writeByteArray# mba# i# b si#) mba#)
                      (f (I# i#))
                      (go (i# +# 1#))
   in (\(MutableByteArrayState s# mba#) ->
         case unsafeFreezeByteArray# mba# s# of
           (# _, ba# #) -> PrimArray ba#) <$>
      (go 0#)
```

Functionally and performance wise they are very close to each other, and in the end they will both produce exactly the same answer. The difference is what the inner loop `go` produces in the end. The latter one will return an applicative containing the closure that can construct the `MutableByteArray#`s, which will later be frozen. While the former has a loop that returns an applicative containing an action that will create a frozen `ByteArray#`s, once an action that can create a `MutableByteArray#` is supplied to it.

Nevertheless, the reason what makes both approaches safe is that each element of every produced array within the loop gets written to exactly once, and each `MutableByteArray#` created does get frozen prior to getting returned by the generating function, but not before it finished writing to them.